Can you use ヲ in translations of foreign names?
For example, if your name was say, William, could you write it as ヲリアム? Or would it have to be ワリアム? (I guess it could also be ウィリアム.)

There is (or was) ヰリアム, too.

Do you say it as 'Wolliam'? Or 'Walliam'? Not only do neither ワ not ヲ fit the pronunciation, ヲ isn't really regarded as 'wo' anyway; nowadays people generally use it as a fanciful way to write オ, as in ヲタク and the like. When a 'wo' sound is wanted in loanwords, ウォ is used, as in ウォーター or ウォーキング
ウィリアム is the normal way to write it
